# Use JQuery after dynamic knockoutJS bindings

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Is there a way to use JQuery after knockoutJS dynamic bindings?

Eg:

```
<!-- ko foreach: editFields -->
<input class='editable' style='display:none' type="text" data-bind="attr: {id: field_id}" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

if field_id = "phone":

```
$('#phone').attr('disabled', true);
```

Or whatever JQuery transformation it just won't happen. I assume bindings are done after all excecutions. so there is no $('#phone') declared.

Is there a way to apply JQuery to this elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is not to use jQuery, but to use KnockoutJS's disabled binding.

In your data bind field, set up both an attribute value for your ID and a disable binding. EG:

```
data-bind="attr: {id: field_id}, disable: disableFlag"
```

Then on your view model, make sure you have a ko observable to drive it EG:

```
this.disableFlag = ko.observable(false);
```

Make sure you actually use a hint value when declaring it, so that KO can determine things correctly.

### Update

To make this easier to understand.  If your using this with a dynamically populated list, then it might be worth creating an actual view model for the rows.

When I first started to work with knockout, I used to just create rows directly off the JSON i was grabbing from my backend, but I quickly found that I was running into a lot of problems making the actual models work exactly how I wanted, so I started to actually compose concrete view models for the rows in the main view model.

I also find it better to compose the models as stand alone objects.

Typically, I'll start with something like this for a row view model:

```
var RowViewModel = (function ()
{
  function RowViewModel(inputRecord)
  {
    this.RecordId = ko.observable(0);
    this.Name = ko.observable('');
    this.SomeOtherData = ko.observable('');
    this.disabledFlag = ko.observable(false);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(inputRecord, {}, this);
  }

  return RowViewModel;
})();
```

Then I build a bigger view model for the main table, list or which ever repeating structure I'm populating, something like the following:

```
var MainViewModel = (function ()
{
  function MainViewModel(targetElement)
  {
    this.loadComplete = ko.observable(false);
    this.tableRows = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.applyBindings(this, targetElement);
    $.support.cors = true;
  }

  IndexViewModel.prototype.Load = function ()
  {
    $.getJSON("/some/place/to/get/data_from", function (data)
    {
      if (data.length > 0)
      {
        _this.tableRows(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item)
        {
          return new RowViewModel(item);
        }));
      } else
      {
        _this.tableRows([]);
      }
      _this.loadComplete(true);
    });
  };

  return IndexViewModel;
})();
```

As you can see, in the main view model, we use the ko utility functions to map our incoming data to a collection of our row view models.

Since each row has a disabled flag on it, setting that to true to disable the row, will put that actual row into a disabled state without needing jQuery.

Comment: Shawty thanks for the answer. The problem I got is a bit different (hence the need of JQuery). I need to disable a field when a checkbox is checked or a value is selected (disable and hide, maybe some other transformations in the future). My approach was to add hardcoded JQuery for these special occasions. Although the disableFlag could be a solution for now. Thanks!

Comment: Dead easy to add something based on a check box.  Just add something that can bind to a check-box binding to your row view model, then wrap that and your disable flag in a computed observable, and voila, a check box that does thy bidding. :-)